# How to override the javascript default editable bootstrap values in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views, x-editable

I am stuck at overriding the default editable bootstrap values in Django framework javascript html page

In my webpage, it coded as below

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.url = "{% url 'page1' model.PATH %}";
```

Now my requirement is,
When I click on a button, it check the views.py(page1, which is default URL) and pass the context through 'return HttpResponse' to html page that "True" or "False"
based the value, if fasle, it should go page2, it never goes to page2 url,its entered to the function conflict_warn() but not inside and eventually it failed with the `Uncaught TypeError:e.getAttribute is not a function`, I tried number of way, but all are vain.

```
$(this).editable({
    value: "",
    display: false,
    success: function (response, newValue) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty("State"))){
    conflict_warn(response, newValue)//if State value True,should go to other func
}
    else {
    window.location.href = "{% url 'path1' 'path2'%}" + response;
}
        },
error: function(response, newValue) { $(this).editable("destroy"); }
    });
$(this).editable("submit");


function conflict_warn(response, newValue) {
    $(this).editable({
        value: ""
    display: false
    success: function (response.newvalue) {
            window.location.href = "{% url 'path1' 'path2'%}" + response;
        }
    });
    $(this).editable("setValue", "{% url 'page1' model.PATH %}");
    $(this).editable("submit");
}
```

Comment: I'd advise you to look at the javascript in the browser developer tools to see how it looks like *after* the template has been processed by Django. This will immediately show you where you make mistakes when writing your {% url %} template tags. (I don't understand "default editable bootstrap values", it's not Django terminology).

Comment: `"{% url:'page1' model.PATH  %}"` is wrong, there shouldn't be a colon after `url`. Also `{% url 'path1' 'path2' %}` makes no sense, check the documentation of the `url` template tag [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions,i miss wrote the url part here, the colon was not there in my code,I wonder what ever approach I followed is the correct for second function conflict_warn()? , still I am not found fix for this.

Comment: Can some one please through some light on this ?

Comment: You need to clarify what's going wrong exactly. Set a breakpoint on the first line inside `success` and go step-by-step. Tell us where you get an error and what the variable values are. I don't understand what is `response` (is it a Json?) and why `response.hasOwnProperty('State')` should return `true`.

Comment: 1. Yes, I set the break point at and found the its exactly failing when cursor reaches to " $(this).editable("setValue", "{% url 'page1' model.PATH %}");
", 2. yes, response is json  3. response.hasOwnProperty('State') -> that's the condition, I am passing True / False from view to html page it should act according to the "State" value.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: So according to what you say, the `conflict_warn` function is correctly called and the line `$(this).editable(“setValue”...)` throws an error? What’s the rest of that line in your browser? It’s definitely not `”{%url ‘page1’ ... %}` because that’s been already evaluated by your Django backend.